# Framework for generating BPEL in runtime?

Tags: runtime, bpel

I need to generate BPEL XML code in runtime. The only way I can do it now is to create XML document with "bare hands" using DOM API. But there must be a framework that could ease such work incorporating some kind of object model.

I guess it should look something like this:

```
BPELProcessFactory.CreateProcess().addSequence
```

Do you know any?

Answer (score 2):

The [Eclipse BPEL designer](http://eclipse.org/bpel) project provides an EMF model for BPEL 2.0. The generated code can be used to programmatically create BPEL code with a convenient API.

Comment: Do you have a working example ?? I am receiving an error as I stated [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15353097/generating-bpel-files-programmatically)  when using eclipse BPEL designer API to generate .bpel file

Comment: Please see my answer below. I have used this code, found from some forum, to create a basic bpel file, but I am unable to modify the code to create the bpel file according to my needs, because I have not found any **documentation** for this code. Can you guide me where to find any guideline on how I would go about modifying this code for advanced bpel functionalities?

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone stumbles upon this.

Yes this can be done using the [BPEL Model](http://www.eclipse.org/bpel/developers/model.php).

Here is a sample piece of code which generates a quite trivial BPEL file:

```
public Process createBPEL()
{
    Process process = null;
    BPELFactory factory = BPELFactory.eINSTANCE;

    try
    {
        ResourceSet rSet = new ResourceSetImpl();
        rSet.getResourceFactoryRegistry().getExtensionToFactoryMap()
                .put("bpel", new BPELResourceFactoryImpl());
        File file = new File("myfile.bpel");
        file.createNewFile();
        String filePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
        System.out.println(filePath);
        AdapterRegistry.INSTANCE.registerAdapterFactory( BPELPackage.eINSTANCE, BasicBPELAdapterFactory.INSTANCE );
        Resource resource = rSet.createResource(URI.createFileURI(filePath));

        process = factory.createProcess();
        process.setName("FirstBPEL");
        Sequence seq = factory.createSequence();
        seq.setName("MainSequence");

        Receive recieve = factory.createReceive();
        PortType portType = new PortTypeProxy(URI.createURI("http://baseuri"), new QName("qname"));
        Operation operation = new OperationProxy(URI.createURI("http://localhost"), portType , "operation_name");
        recieve.setOperation(operation);

        Invoke invoke = factory.createInvoke();
        invoke.setOperation(operation);


        While whiles = factory.createWhile();
        If if_st = factory.createIf();

        List<Activity> activs = new ArrayList<Activity>();

        activs.add(recieve);
        activs.add(invoke);
        activs.add(if_st);
        activs.add(whiles);


        seq.getActivities().addAll(activs);

        process.setActivity(seq);

        resource.getContents().add(process);

        Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("bpel", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsbpel/2.0/process/executable");
        map.put("xsd", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");

        resource.save(map);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return process;
}
```

The dependencies require that you add the following jars to the project's build path from the **plugins** folder in eclipse installation directory:

> - org.eclipse.bpel.model_*.jar
> - org.eclipse.wst.wsdl_*.jar
> - org.eclipse.emf.common_*.jar
> - org.eclipse.emf.ecore_*.jar
> - org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi_*.jar
> - javax.wsdl_*.jar
> - org.apache.xerces_*.jar
> - org.eclipse.bpel.common.model_*.jar
> - org.eclipse.xsd_*.jar
> - org.eclipse.core.resources_*.jar
> - org.eclipse.osgi_*.jar
> - org.eclipse.core.runtime_*.jar
> - org.eclipse.equinox.common_*.jar
> - org.eclipse.core.jobs_*.jar
> - org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility_*.jar